# Hadoop eclipse plugin stopped working

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, mapreduce

hi all i am using hadoop2.2.0 and eclipse juno and hadoop eclipse plug in it was working fine before but suddenly it stopped working it not even showing dfs locations in eclipse plz help it showing following error

```
Plug-in org.apache.hadoop.eclipse was unable to load class org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.view.servers.ServerView.
```

and this is error log

```
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

This is a continuation of log file /home/sumit/workspace/.metadata/.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-06-15 14:07:21.872

Error
Sun Jun 15 14:07:21 IST 2014
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.navigator".

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: No property tester contributes a property mapreduce.deployable to type class org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TypeExtensionManager.getProperty(TypeExtensionManager.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.AdaptExpression.evaluate(AdaptExpression.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateOr(CompositeExpression.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.OrExpression.evaluate(OrExpression.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPlugin$Evaluator.run(NavigatorPlugin.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.CustomAndExpression.evaluate(CustomAndExpression.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPlugin$Evaluator.run(NavigatorPlugin.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorPlugin.safeEvaluate(NavigatorPlugin.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentDescriptor.isTriggerPoint(NavigatorContentDescriptor.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentDescriptorManager.findDescriptors(NavigatorContentDescriptorManager.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.NavigatorContentDescriptorManager.findDescriptorsForTriggerPoint(NavigatorContentDescriptorManager.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentService.findDescriptorsByTriggerPoint(NavigatorContentService.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentService.findContentExtensionsByTriggerPoint(NavigatorContentService.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentService.findContentExtensionsByTriggerPoint(NavigatorContentService.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:377)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.hasChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2138)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.isExpandable(TreeViewer.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.isExpandable(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.optionallyPruneChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2808)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.updateChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2608)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1923)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1930)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.internalRefreshStruct(TreeViewer.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1898)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.internalRefresh(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1855)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.internalRefresh(CommonViewer.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$8.run(StructuredViewer.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1443)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.refresh(CommonViewer.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.refresh(CommonViewer.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.WorkingSetActionProvider.setWorkingSet(WorkingSetActionProvider.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.WorkingSetActionProvider.initWorkingSetFilter(WorkingSetActionProvider.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.WorkingSetActionProvider$4.run(WorkingSetActionProvider.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3529)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3182)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably switched Perspective. Go to `Window` -> `Open Perspective` -> `Other` and choose `Map/Reduce`. This should also bring you back `DFS Locations`.